# GoDaddy DNS to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns

.sg domain with webvisions (unable to transfer due to some issues)
application with AWS beanstalk
wordpress hosting and email hosting with goDaddy

Am trying to link my .sg domain for my email, wordpress and application

How do I edit my GoDaddy DNS so that

domain.sg--> AWS beanstalk
corporate.domain.sg--> godaddy's domain hosting (wordpress)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this setup you cant point "domain.sg" to beanstalk directly. You will need to point for example www.domain.sg to elastic beanstalk with a CNAME record. In godaddy you can configure a forwarder from "domain.sg" to "www.domain.sg". This means that when users enter "domain.sg" in their browsers they first hit a godaddy webserver that then forwards them to "www.domain.sg". If you want to use "domain.sg" you will need to use Route53 (change nameservers in godaddy to those of your Route53 hosted zone).